# How can i view mail using doveadm?

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have mail sent to my dovecot inbox and I can see that there are unread emails.
If I run:

```
doveadm -f table mailbox status -u bob all INBOX
```

I get:

```
mailbox messages recent uidnext uidvalidity unseen highestmodseq vsize guid                             firstsaved
INBOX   2        2      3       1581074875  2      3             37815 26782a22bb493d5e3e070000fb112bbd 1581074773
```

How can i read these unread messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd use an IMAP client to access mail, as Dovecot is an IMAP server...

```
mutt -f imap://bob@localhost/INBOX
```

As a trick, it is possible with some IMAP clients to talk directly to Dovecot, bypassing authentication:

```
mutt -e 'set tunnel="sudo doveadm exec imap -u bob"' -f imap://nothing/INBOX
```

---

But if you need to extract the messages directly, use `doveadm fetch` or `doveadm search`:

```
doveadm fetch -u bob "text" MAILBOX INBOX UNSEEN
```

Parameters are similar to IMAP – `text` is a [fetch field](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Fetch) that contains the entire RFC822 message, the rest are a [search query](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/SearchQuery) that finds unread messages in the INBOX folder.